# Swapped in new SAS drive, RAID still shows degraded, what next?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, sas, dell-perc

I need to replace a failed RAID 1 drive on an ancient PowerEdge 2950. The old drive was throwing amber warning lights with the LED showing error 1810.

I have a new SAS drive installed and the controller appears to see it. There are two solid green leds on the new drive:

[image]

I've booted into the OS and waited 30 minutes, but it does not appear to be rebuilding the drive.

Rebooting back into Ctrl-R, on the PD tab, I'm showing the new drive is in a Ready state:

[image]

But, PERC shows that disk 1 is Missing:

[image]

What do I need to do here to tell Perc to manually rebuild the RAID 1 array with the newly installed and Ready drive?

Answer (score 1):

Finally gathered courage to hot swap the new drive while the OS was up. That was all I needed to do to begin with.

OMSA showing the new drive is in rebuild state:

[image]